# The best unique hit

Tags: python

Example input file,

```
name1 name1 100
name1 name2 99.4
name1 name3 67.8
name1 name4 40.2
name2 name2 100
name2 name1 98
```

I would like to 1) group by 1st column 2) compare name column1 and 2 and if it is the same, ignore 3) print the line with the highest value. So my output is,

```
name1 name2 99.4
name2 name1 98
```

My try, if I use sort instead of max my best hit disappears.

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
with open('input.txt','rb') as f1:
    with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f2:
        reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter='\t')
        writer1 = csv.writer(f2, delimiter='\t')
        for group, rows in groupby(reader, itemgetter(0)):
            for line in rows:
                 if line[0] == line[1]:
                     continue
                 else:
                     best = max(rows, key=lambda r: (float(r[2])))
                     writer1.writerow(best)
```

Comment: please explain a bit more why your current code does not produce the result you expect. What is your expected output ?

Comment: my output is above,it gives me an error or max() arg empty seq-s, I could write two separate scripts to do this..but i want 1 script for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd `filter` the unnecessary lines, then group by first column and `max` by the last:

```
with open('input.txt','rb') as f1:
    with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f2:
        reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter='\t')
        writer1 = csv.writer(f2, delimiter='\t')
        out_rows = [
            max(g, key=lambda x: float(x[2]) for k, g in groupby(
                filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1], reader), key=itemgetter(0)
            )
        ]       
        writer1.writerows(out_rows)
```

Comment: it says: TypeError: filter() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @user3224522 Yeah, of course. Filter's signature is the other way round compared to max and groupby. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rows` iterator returned by `groupby()` is iterated twice, once in `for line in rows:`, the other in `max(rows)`. The iterator will eventually be depleted, leading to the error you have.

First create a list out of your `rows` iterator, you will then be able to iterate over it multiple times.